# for loop in recursive function python

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

I tried to use for loop in a recursive function to find all path that the child class related to its parents.

```
class A:
    pass
class B(A):
    pass
class C(A):
    pass
class F(A):
    pass
class L(C,B):
    pass
class D(B,F):
    pass
class M(L,D):
    pass


def bases(cls):
    if cls == object:
        return [object]
    
    for Class in cls.__bases__:
        return [cls] + bases(Class)


print(bases(M))
# the output should be this:
# [[M, L, C, A], [M, L, B, A], [M, D, B, A], [M, D, F, A]]
```

but the output is `[M, L, C, A]` . keyword Return didn't allow  For Loop to do well .  then I wrote the code like this:

```
for Class in cls.__bases__:
    path = [cls] + bases(Class)
return path
```

and the output would be `[M, D, F, A]` . I replaced `return` with `yield` but it didn't work and I get error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "generator") to list
```

what can I do to solve this problem???

Comment: Try to checkup the type of each return, it seems that when you are doing the recursion to see which is the generator. And check the call stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following implementation using recursion:

```py
class A:
    pass
class B(A):
    pass
class C(A):
    pass
class F(A):
    pass
class L(C,B):
    pass
class D(B,F):
    pass
class M(L,D):
    pass

def bases(cls):
    if cls.__bases__ == (object, ): # if "root"
        return [cls.__name__]
    return [[cls.__name__, *granpas] for base in cls.__bases__ for granpas in bases(base)]

print(bases(M)) # [['M', 'L', 'C', 'A'], ['M', 'L', 'B', 'A'], ['M', 'D', 'B', 'A'], ['M', 'D', 'F', 'A']]
```